# Encoding problems (switching between Japanese and English encoding)

Tags: texshop, cjk, input-encodings

I seem to have messed up the encoding of my tex document in TexShop and I wonder if anyone can explain to me what's going on?

I had a short document which was fine, until I needed to add some Japanese, so I added

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

at the top line and then

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{goth} % for gothic (sans serif) font
\CJKnormal

% Cite English reference
\cite{UK2013}

% Cite Japanese reference
\cite{Japan2012}

\bibliographystyle{custom}
\bibliography{references}

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

After doing this, all my backslashes changed to yen signs, and any backslash I typed came up in the editing window as a yen sign.

Now when I compile it has an error

```
"Missing \begin{document}"
```

and shows an error

```
DOT documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
```

where DOT is literally a dot.

So it's clear that the backslashes have all been lost.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on with the encoding, and how I can fix it?

I am aware of XeTeX, but I heard that by adding lines from  the package CJKutf8 as I have done above, it is possible to avoid having to install another huge Latex implementation just for the use of Japanese characters.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: To me this sounds very much like a problem TeXShop is having, as I am able to compile your source code without any problems. I have experienced that TeXShop somehow does not like you changing the file’s encoding afterwards (e. g. by adding `%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` after you have saved it for the first time). One solution I have found is opening the corrupt file in an editor which lets you choose the file’s encoding in the opening dialog (TextWrangler, SublimeText 2, …) and then saving/exporting it again with the correct encoding. I am not sure if this answers your question ;)

Comment: The change from backslash to the yen symbol seems to be characteristic of the Shift-JIS encoding. I tried changing the encoding in TeXShop, but I didn't succeed in reproducing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Following your hints I switched from Texshop (to vim), and now there are no encoding problems.

Comment: FYI, XeTeX should already be included in your distribution, and would allow you to use much nicer Japanese fonts. Try changing the typesetting engine in TeXShop, or just add `%!TEX TS-program = xelatex` to your file header.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible (see other comments) and is likely a localised issue with encoding.

Comment: thank you so much for the '%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode' line. i was installing packages and everything and having trouble on the mac and that fixed my doc